# Error when adding DateTimePicker from PnP SPFx React controls

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, pnp, react

I'm having problem when adding DateTimePicker from the @pnp/spfx-controls-react collection. Once added in the render() method, I'm seeing *<DateTimePicker* name underlined and following error:

```
'DateTimePicker' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'DateTimePicker' is not a valid JSX element.
    Types of property 'refs' are incompatible.
      Type '{ [key: string]: import("c:/Users/[...]/source/repos/BnpViews/node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactInstance; }' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: React.ReactInstance; }'.
        Index signatures are incompatible.
          Type 'import("c:/Users/[...]/source/repos/BnpViews/node_modules/@pnp/spfx-controls-react/node_modules/@types/react/index").ReactInstance' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactInstance'.
            Type 'Component<any, {}, any>' is not assignable to type 'ReactInstance'.
              Type 'Component<any, {}, any>' is not assignable to type 'Component<any, {}>'.
                The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
                  Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.
                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'false | Element'.ts(2786)
```

My component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IBnpViewsPanelProps } from './IBnpViewsPanelProps';

import styles from './BnpViewsPanel.module.scss';
import { DateTimePicker, DateConvention } from '@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/dateTimePicker';

export interface IBnpViewsPanelState {
  date: Date|null;
}

export default class BnpViewsPanel extends React.Component<IBnpViewsPanelProps, IBnpViewsPanelState> {
  constructor(props: IBnpViewsPanelProps){
    super(props);

    this.setState({date: null});
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<IBnpViewsPanelProps> {
    return(
      <DateTimePicker label="test" dateConvention={DateConvention.Date} value={this.state.date}/>
    );
  }



}
```

My packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.4.0",
    "@pnp/sp": "^2.0.12",
    "@pnp/spfx-controls-react": "2.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2"
  },
  "
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are using SPFx 1.4 with spfx-controls-react 2.2.0. I believe v2 requires 1.11.0 for SPFx. If you stick with 1.4 you must use V1. https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-controls-react/ brings this up, I'm just not sure if I am reading this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @m1g suggested in the comment, the problem was with SPFx version vs spfx-controls-react version. Once I've downgraded the controls to 1.x everything started to run smoothly.